# What is the correct translation and usage of "sleep"?

Tags: sentence-translation, english-to-latin-translation

I'm trying to helping out my friend to write a story, the story has a scene where there is Latin sentences which the only sentence that I suppose to be written in Latin in the story but I can't figure it out.

So can anyone of you translate this?

> Don't wake me up from my sleep.
>   And yet… will I see the light again?

I tried to use Google Translate, but it seems something off/odd with the "wake" and "sleep" part. So please let me know the correct translation.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice question! Google translate is usually not a good tool for Latin, but in order to be on-topic, we've agreed that you have to show some previous effort, so you may want to add what did Google give you and why you think it's odd

Comment: Hi! and thanks for warm welcome, I tried to roughly translate from google translate and did little search with the result of translation and online dictionary. I almost have zero knowledge in latin but based on my search seems the result a little bit off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my attempt. I'm not specially good with translations, but I want to give it a try. Due to the way in which I have learnt Latin, it will have a post-classical flavor:

> Noli me de somno meo suscitare
>
> Numquid autem lucem denuo videbo?

A couple of notes:

- As you may note, Draconis preferred not to use *noli* because it sounds harsh. The alternative here would be *ne me de somno suscites*. *Noli* is the imperative form of a verb meaning *not to want*, and, as far as I know, is a standard form of saying *don't*. I agree that *ne* is more polite, but I perceive *noli* just as neutral as the original *don't*.
- [Somnus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsomnus) means primarily *sleep*, but also *dream, drowsiness, night, death*, in a wider sense. *To sleep* is *dormire* (*I sleep*, *dormio*.)
- The verb *suscitare* literally means *to raise* sth *up* but is commonly used in the context of someone sleeping to mean *to wake someone up* (e.g. [VG Act 12:7](http://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_nt_actus-apostolorum_lt.html#12), and also classically.) Another verb is *evigilare*, but I'm hesitant about its proper usage. I also thought of *educere* as saying *take me out of my dream*, but I now think its further apart from what you originally meant.
- The way to link *suscitare* with *I* is through the accusative *me*.
- The way to link *suscitare* with *somnus* is with one of two prepositions: either *de somno* (cf. [Gen 28:16](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0060:book=Genesis:chapter=28&highlight=somno%2Csomnis%2Cevigilasset)) or *e(x) somno* (as suggested by [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsuscito), probably the Classical way to do it.)
- *Numquid* is a standard interrogatory particle. *Num* is equivalent, and I think more used in classical times.
- [*Autem*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dautem) is an adversative conjunction than can perfectly translate to *but*, and (usually?) needs to be the second word of the sentence. Both *num autem* and *numquid autem* are attested at some point in Latin history. Particularly, *num autem* is attested by Pliny the Younger (I-II cent. AD.)
- *[Denuo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddenuo)* is a rather uncommon adverb, but its primary meanings are *anew, afresh, again*.
- *Videbo* and *aspiciam* are both 1st person singular, future tense of verbs meaning *to see* (I will/will I see.) To me it seems that *[aspicio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daspicio)* is more prone to mean to look at (with attention, in detail), while [*video*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvideo) is more directly to see/perceive with the eyes, just as your phrase seems to be desperately looking for.

Comment: Very nice explanation! really extensive explanation, and based on your analysis, I think we prefer "somnus" over "quiēte". It just sounds that the "sleep" sounds a lil bit meaningful. Just one question, is it appropriate to use Aurora instead? and what the difference between videbo and videre? because I saw them a lil bit more in internet, but I'm not certain. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @tronic __Aurora__ = *dawn, daybreak, morning*. Perhaps you read *aurora borealis* meant the northern lights? Yes, but they were not called *lights* in Latin (nor are in some modern Romance languages.) __Videbo__ = *I will see* or *will I see*; videre = *to see*, not quite fit here

Comment: @tronic Let us know if/when the story gets published!

Answer (score 4):

I would say it like this:

> Nē mē ē quiēte cieās. Sed…rursus lūcem aspiciam?

(EDIT: Standard disclaimer: the lines over the vowels are optional. I use them but many other people don't; they represent a distinction between sounds that disappeared in later Latin.)

The first sentence is fairly straightforward. Instead of the harsh *nōlī*+inf "don't…" I used *nē*+subj "please don't…", with the verb *cieō* "to move, to rouse". For sleep I used the rather poetic *quiēs* "rest, quiet".

The second sentence I'm less happy with. *Sed* and *rursus* are both rather prosaic words, and I feel there *must* be a more poetic way to say "ever again", but I don't know it. (*Rursus* is closer to "a second time".) *Lūcem* comes from *lūx* "light, daylight", often used figuratively to mean "life" (as in Aeneid 4, *Anna refert, o lūci magis dilēcta sorōri* "Anna replies, 'oh, you, more beloved to your sister than her own life'") and the verb is *aspiciō* "behold" in the subjunctive.

Comment: I don't really know if this helps, but the OP uses just "again" rather than "ever again."

Comment: Whoa this is useful, but I still uncertain in few parts, I will add comment once I'm home (I already upvote but due to my low rep, it is not displayed).  

And I think we don't mind to use "ever again" instead, since it just mean the same after all

Comment: I've arrived home and read your answer, I have certain things in mind to ask aside from your interesting notes; is it more appropriate to use quiēte rather than somne / somnus? what the difference between them? And also, Lūcem means light (daylight), how about Aurora? its not like I'm not satisfied, It just me that interested with those particular words. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @tronic _aurora_ means light only by a far fetched analogy. Look at this [dictionary entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daurora)