# How to say "Do not be ..." in Latin?

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, imperative

I want to write a motto for self-control: Don't be a slave!

Google Translate translated that to: "Ne fiat servus".

I do not know whether that is correct, or whether I should write "servis" insead.

So, What would be a better translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, [Google Translate is horrible with Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79) and should not be trusted at all.
It fails here, too.
I would translate "Ne fiat servus" as "May he not become a slave".
It is a reasonable wish for a third party, but not what you wanted to express.

There is a simple way to say "don't X" in Latin:
just say *noli X*, where *X* is an infinitive form of a verb.
The verb "to be" is *esse*, so "don't be" would be *noli esse*.
Then we need to add the slave, and it should be in the singular nominative form *servus*.
(*Servis* would be plural dative of ablative.)
This construction is attested in classical Latin; [see this question for details](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6750/79).

This leads to:
***Noli esse servus.***

Comment: Somehow I would expect something more compact than _noli esse_, but I can't think what. _Noli servare_ would not mean the same thing.

Comment: @ColinFine *Noli servare* is a good option! Can you give that as a separate answer? I am always happy to see a number of answers proposing different approaches.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thank you so much for this detailed answer, yes, even though I do not know Latin, I sensed that something is wrong with Google translate... Best +1 !

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: the reason I did not give _noli servare_ as a separate answer is that I'm  not sure it fits. In English "do not serve" and "do not be a servant" (never mind "a slave") are rather different, and I don't know whether that difference carries over into Latin or not.

Comment: 2022 update: Google Translate is much better at Latin now, and it suggests almost the same translation as you did: “Noli servus esse!”

Comment: @Anserin If you have updates on how Google fares with Latin nowadays, you can always write up an answer to the linked Google question. The question and the other answers contain plenty of examples to check for improvement.